# How could I know I am using ES6 in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I am trying to use react.js. 
I found a question while I am reading the "get started with react".
(link : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)

Middle of the page, there is a statement,

> Note: If you are using ES2015, you will want to also use the
>   babel-preset-es2015 package.

However, I do not know how to find which one I am using. How could I find which one I am using?

SUM >> How could I know ES version?

Comment: If you don't know it - you are not using it.

Comment: Also not that the **new** convention is using year numbers, so you're trying to determine if you're using ES2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I do not know how to find which one I am using. How could I find which one I am using?

You can check in the `package.json` of your project. Normally, you will find under the `devDependencies` property something that looks this way: `"babel-preset-es2015": "x.y.z"` (x.y.z being the version you use)

It refers to this [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) package

Hope this helps.

EDIT: the answer to your question:

> SUM >> How could I know ES version?

is pretty straightforward. Check [ES2015 specific syntatic](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) features in your codebase.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what if I do not use nodejs? Still I am using certain version of ECMAScript. I want to know version of ES.

Comment: if babel is not present, you can still use ES6. that´s not really a reliable information.

Comment: @luschn I agree, but my answer was very specific. I was pointing to the part of the question about babel-preset-es2015. Not to wether their code is in ES6 or not.

Comment: his main question was "How could I know ES version?", not "am i using babel?" or "which babel version am i using?" ;) - but nevermind, i just think this should be a comment because it does not answer the question.

Comment: It seems like it depends on what js engine of my browser / Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `import xy from './xy'` to request your modules, you are using ES6. If you are using `var xy = require('./xy')` to request your modules, you are not. ES6 offers a lot more than that though, but there are hundreds of articles about that already. For example classes are new in ES6. Btw, ES6 = ECMAScript 2015: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript

Also, if you are using Babel in your project, you are using ES6. For older Browsers, you need to "transpile" the code to work.

Btw, every developer should have heard of ES6 by now, and i highly recommend using it already.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer points some features of ES6. However, my question was how to know my ES version.(sorry for miscommunication)

Comment: import is one of the major features of ES6, so if you have import statements and classes in your code, you are using ES6. if not, an older version. bzw. ES6=ECMAScript 2015.

Comment: i´ve added a link to wikipedia. but as zerkms commented on your question: if you don´t know it, you are not using it.